# How to revoke right to a usergroup on a certain date in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, date, database-design, role, rights

I'm currently creating a DB with Postgresql. First time, be gentle. ;)

I have a table `project` that stores submission date among other things.

I have 2 groups of users. One can only consult the database, no update/insert/delete rights, so it's quite easy.

The other group has the rights to do whatever they want on their project, but only until the submission date.

I'm looking for a nice way to do it.

I thought at a trigger function that checks the `current_date` and the date stored in the DB, and revokes the rights if it is passed, then raise an exception 'You don't have the rights anymore to modify that project.
I could use that same trigger on all my tables.
I think that could work, but I don't know if that the right/nice way to do it.

PS: If someone also has some tip about 1..* to 0..* relation…

Comment: What relation? You mentioned a single table `project` ...

Answer (score 1):

Privileges are granted per object. You cannot grant privileges per row directly with `GRANT` / `REVOKE`.

One way around this would be a `VIEW` that only shows not-yet-submitted projects. Simple for `SELECT` privileges, more complicated for `UPDATE` / `DELETE`. You'd need [`INSTEAD` rules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createrule.html) on the view, which gets tricky, especially for beginners.

The other obvious option is what you already had in mind, just simpler. You don't have to actually revoke privileges. Just throw an exception for submitted projects:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_p_updelno()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
IF pg_has_role('other_group', 'member')
   AND OLD.submission_date < now()::date THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Too late, Kate! Project already submitted.';
END IF;

RETURN NULL;

END
$func$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER updelno
BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON project
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_p_updelno();
```

`pg_has_role()` is one of the [Access Privilege Inquiry Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE), which should come in handy.

Of course, you would want to keep those users from editing the submission date. You could do that in the trigger as well.
But be careful when referring to `NEW` in a trigger function that can be fired `ON DELETE`, where `NEW` does not exist. Have a look at the [examples in the manual using `TG_OP` here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can consider is that if group two is going to have no access to the db after a specific date, you can revoke their login permissions at that point.  Note how depends on authentication specifics but if it is password login, you just:

```
ALTER USER foo VALID UNTIL '2013-07-01';
```

Note this only expires the password.  You could then have a cron job which goes through periodically and cleans up expired users (info is in pg_authid system table).

If the users will still have access to the PostgreSQL instance, you will need to go with Erwin's suggestions.